# Table rates shipping option showing in frontend while it is disabled

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods

In my magento store when I disable `table rates` shipping option from admin still it is showing on checkout page as shipping option.

How to disable `table rates` shipping option?

Comment: did you selected `Default config` under `current configuration scope` ?

Comment: Yes, My store is not multi website/store.

Comment: did you enabled any other shipping mehtod, if you disable that shipping method, is that one will display on `checkout` ?

Comment: Yes, Enabled free shipping option and it is also showing in shipping methods.

Comment: if you hide `free shipping` will it display in checkout, also is any other shipping related modules enabled , try disabling 3-party modules and check....

Comment: enter `minimum order amount` to 1000000 under `table rate shipping` and check

Answer (score 0):

Check that same configuration on website lavel and Disable that also Or set as global.

Answer (score 0):

delete cache folder from var. and open site in new private window or new browser.

Comment: I have clear all cache and also checked in incognito browser but the option still showing, if I made any changes with label/title then it is reflected on frontend.

Comment: apply backend setting on store level and global level

Comment: How to apply backend setting on store level?

Comment: sorry its my mistack. ones you clear session and cache and check. or any other extension you add that effact the table rate.

Comment: No, there is no extension for it.